# Meet "You do not have permissions to make this API call" after change from http1.0 to http1.1

Tags: paypal, permissions

Recently I check from http1.0 to http1.1 due to https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details?eventId=4283 . After that , I met the error: Error calling paypal API: SetExpressCheckout; error message = PayPal API SetExpressCheckout Invocation get the following error: Error code = 10002, Error message = You do not have permissions to make this API call. I didn't change any changes of account and other code than http1.1. It's paypal sandbox env 
Could someone can help on this?

Comment: Finally I fixed this problem by avoid use axis CommonsHttpSender. I use a self owned class like public class my HttpSender extends HTTPSender {

@Override
public void invoke(MessageContext msgContext) throws AxisFault {
if(msgContext!=null)
{
msgContext.setProperty(MessageContext.HTTP_TRANSPORT_VERSION, HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_V11);
}
super.invoke(msgContext);
}

}

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this change is to upgrade to the latest version of appropriate SDK from https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages.